# Grails Spring Security LDAP "defaultRole" does not get assigned

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap

I'm struggling with LDAP authorization in Grails (authentication works). This is my configuration:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter = 'sAMAccountName={0}'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.defaultRole = 'ROLE_USER'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = true   
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = false    
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.useRememberMe = false
```

I'm expection the user to get assigned the 'ROLE_USER' role but all I get is:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@d66fe506: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d66fe506: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl@d66d0e48: Dn: cn=testuser,cn=Users,dc=GROUP,dc=LOCAL; Username: testuser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd148a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 2BA8D2C334CBDA358EEEAD97F12DD38C; Not granted any authorities'
```

Do you have any word of wisdom? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record I found out the solution is to switch retrieveGroupRoles to true:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = true
```